# Zero crossing detector using 311 comparator

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

[image]

Is the explanation correct? The output on positive voltage should be high and on negative voltage it should be low.

Comment: Why the `741-opamp` tag? It has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: okay! but can you answer it for lm311 comparator?

Comment: I already did. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. The diagram is weird as it is using logic inverter symbols for an analog comparitor and I suspect the author confused him/herself with this.

- When IN+ goes high the comparator (trianglular part) goes high and the inverter (circle after the triangle) makes it low and turns off the NPN transistor. The output is then pulled heigh.

Comment: yes! the bubbles at input and output of the block are more confusing and also the explanation is totally wrong taking in account the operationand pinout of 311 comparator!